# How to disable ionic side menu in the desktop?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I want to have the same ionic toggle menu in both mobile and web application.
I don't know how to disable the side menu.

Comment: read here https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-disable-side-menu-in-ionic-4/138098/6

Comment: what do you mean by disable menu?